# Flutter desktop support for reading serial port input

Tags: flutter

I what to build flutter desktop application for linux ubuntu. The application needs to read from the serial port of the desktop. The use case is I will be connecting a weight machine to my desktop using RS232. Are there any API available in flutter that can read the weight and show it in the application.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to read weight? Can you provide solution?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, it's only available for IOS and Android.`usb_serial: ^0.2.4`
More details would be helpful if you provide what exactly you want to read for alternative solutions.

**Edit:**

check out
`flutter_libserialport: ^0.2.0` https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport/example
`libserialport: ^0.2.0+2` https://pub.dev/packages/libserialport

Comment: Please see my comment above I have updated the question